# How to make html drag and drop only accept videos

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm using this HTML code to upload video files to my website.

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form method="post" action="#" id="#">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group files">
                    <label class="d-flex justify-content-center">Upload Your File </label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" multiple="" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*">
                </div>
                <div class="row row-cols-auto">
                    <div class="col mx-auto my-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Upload</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
.files input {
outline: 2px dashed #92b0b3;
outline-offset: -10px;
-webkit-transition: outline-offset .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s linear;
transition: outline-offset .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s linear;
padding: 120px 0px 85px 35%;
text-align: center !important;
margin: 0;
width: 100% !important;
}
.files input:focus{     outline: 2px dashed #92b0b3;  outline-offset: -10px;
    -webkit-transition: outline-offset .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s 
linear;
    transition: outline-offset .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s linear; 
border:1px solid #92b0b3;
}
.files{ position:relative}
.files:after {  pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    right: 0;
    height: 56px;
    content: "";
    background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/109/109612.png);
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.color input{ background-color:#f1f1f1;}
.files:before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;  pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    height: 57px;
    content: " or drag it here. ";
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #2ea591;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-align: center;
}
```

when I click on the input and select a file it only allows me to select videos. But I can easily still drag and drop any different type of file to the input field.

Is there any way to prevent dropping other file types except videos to the field?

Thank you.

Also I'm using django as the backend if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

in your javascript use

replace 'file' with .mp4 or what ever file type you use

```
if (item.kind === 'file') {
        const file = item.getAsFile();
        console.log(`… file[${i}].name = ${file.name}`);
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Use DataTransfer interface to access the file(s)
    [...ev.dataTransfer.files].forEach((file, i) => {
      console.log(`… file[${i}].name = ${file.name}`);
    });
  }
}
```